# Calculating accuracy from precision, recall, f1-score - scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, precision-recall

I made a huge mistake. I printed output of scikit-learn svm accuracy as:

```
str(metrics.classification_report(trainExpected, trainPredict, digits=6))
```

Now I need to calculate accuracy from following output:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

1             0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1259
2             0.500397  1.000000  0.667019      1261
avg / total   0.250397  0.500397  0.333774      2520
```

Is it possible to calculate accuracy from these values?

PS: I don't want to spend another day for getting outputs of the model. I just realized this mistake hopefully I don't need to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to spend more time on it. The `metrics` [module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#model-evaluation.) has everything you need in it and you have already computed the predicted values. It's a one line change.

```
print(metrics.accuracy_score(trainExpected, trainPredict))
```

I suggest that you spend some time to read the linked page to learn more about evaluating models in general.

I do think you have a bigger problem with at hand -- you have zero predicted values for your `1` class, despite having balanced classes. You likely have a problem in your data,  modeling strategy, or code that you'll have to deal with.

Comment: You are correct with predicted values, I didn't see that at first. I work with large number of samples and features and that takes a lot time. What I mean by spending time is actually waiting for the outputs of each input. One line change is correct, but I was trying to find a calculation method for accuracy over these values (by parsing values from these results), in order not to start from beginning and writing the scores to the file. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the accuracy from precision, recall and number of true/false positives or in your case support (even if precision or recall were 0 due to a 0 numerator or denominator).

```
TruePositive+FalseNegative=Support_True
TrueNegative+FalsePositive=Support_False
Precision=TruePositive/(TruePositive+FalsePositive) if TruePositive+FalsePositive!=0 else 0
Recall=TruePositive/(TruePositive+FalseNegative) if TruePositive+FalseNegative!=0 else 0
Accuracy=(TruePositive+TrueNegative)/(TruePositive+TrueNegative+FalsePositive+FalseNegative)
```

-or-
Given TruePositive/TrueNegative counts for example then:

```
TPP=TruePositive/Precision=TruePositive+FalsePositive if Precision!=0 and TruePositive!=0 else TPP=0
TPR=TruePositive/Recall=TruePositive+FalseNegative if Recall!=0 and TruePositive!=0 else TPR=0
```

In the above, when TruePositive==0, then no computation is possible without more information about FalseNegative/FalsePositive.  Hence the support is better.

```
Accuracy=(TruePositive+TrueNegative)/(TPP+TPR-TruePositive+TrueNegative)
```

But in your case given was support so we use recall:

```
Recall=TruePositive/Support_True if Support_True!=0 else 0
TruePositive=Recall*Support_True, likewise TrueNegative=Recall_False*Support_False in all cases
Accuracy=(Recall*Support_True+Recall_False*Support_False)/(Support_True + Support_False)
```

In your case `(0*1259+1*1261)/(1259+1261)=0.500397` which is exactly what you would expect when only one class is predicted.  The respective precision score becomes the accuracy in that case.

Like the other poster said, better to use the library.  But since this sounded like potentially a mathematical question as well, this can be used.