# Getting accuracy for each category in a multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science

I need to calculate the accuracy for each category (NOT the overall accuracy) in a multi-label classification problem. It is easy to find the precision, recall and F-score for each category using `classification_report` from `scikit-learn` library. There are 13 categories distributed as follows:

```
                   precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Category 1       0.58      0.48      0.53       244
     Category 2       0.91      0.85      0.88       728
     Category 3       0.90      0.92      0.91      1319
     Category 4       0.70      0.55      0.62       533
     Category 5       1.00      0.10      0.18        20
     Category 6       0.94      0.84      0.89      2038
     Category 7       0.83      0.78      0.80      1930
     Category 8       0.85      0.44      0.58       113
     Category 9       0.88      0.87      0.87      1329
     Category 10      0.79      0.54      0.64        61
     Category 11      0.81      0.77      0.79       562
     Category 12      0.71      0.62      0.66       416
     Category 13      0.76      0.60      0.67       500

      micro avg       0.86      0.78      0.82      9793
      macro avg       0.82      0.64      0.69      9793
   weighted avg       0.85      0.78      0.81      9793
    samples avg       0.86      0.82      0.83      9793
```

I know that accuracy can be found as follows:     `Accuracy=(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)` but finding `TP` and `TN` for this multi-lable classifcation problem was an issue for me.

There is a similar question to this one on stackoverflow [Calculating accuracy from precision, recall, f1-score - scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041078/calculating-accuracy-from-precision-recall-f1-score-scikit-learn)
but for binary-classification problems only.

**Note:**
I have tried `multilabel_confusion_matrix` and `confusion_matrix` from sklearn.metrics to extract the confusion matrix, but both gave me the same following error: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets`

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can create a 13 x 13 matrix and calculate the individual metrics as one vs rest

Comment: Please use [`multilabel_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix.html) instead, and update your question with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually compute the per-class accuracy from the original arrays with the following code:

```
class_accuracies = []
for class_ in np.unique(y_true):
    class_acc = np.mean(y_pred[y_true == class_] == class_)
    class_acuracies.append(class_acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check formula for accuracy per label. In multilabel classifiers you can find accuracy per label(class) and accuracy per instance.